# Selecting first group of rows in case second group is duplicate

Tags: sas

I have data like below (Dataset name - Have)

```
ID   NAME  AMOUNT PREFER
ABC  Test1  123   Pref1
ABC  Test1  456   Pref1
ABC  Test1  789   Pref1
ABC  Test1  123   Pref2
ABC  Test1  456   Pref2
ABC  Test1  789   Pref2
```

and i want First Group only as output

```
ID   NAME  AMOUNT PREFER
ABC  Test1  123   Pref1
ABC  Test1  456   Pref1
ABC  Test1  789   Pref1
```

Tried so far. simple data step like

```
Data want;
set have;
by ID PREFER;
if first.PREFER;
run;
```

This will give me

```
ID   NAME  AMOUNT PREFER
ABC  Test1  123   Pref1
ABC  Test1  123   Pref2
```

Please suggest something in Data Step or Proc SQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds as though you probably want something like this:

```
data have;
input ID $ NAME $ AMOUNT PREFER $;
cards;
ABC  Test1  123   Pref1
ABC  Test1  456   Pref1
ABC  Test1  789   Pref1
ABC  Test1  123   Pref2
ABC  Test1  456   Pref2
ABC  Test1  789   Pref2
run;

data want;
set have;
by id;
retain t_prefer;
if first.id then t_prefer = prefer;
if prefer = t_prefer;
drop t_prefer;
run;
```

The trick is to use a `retain` statement so that a copy of the value of `prefer` from the first row per id is carried over between iterations of the data step, and you can then output only rows with that value of `prefer`.

Answer (score 0):

You could just keep track of which group number the current record is in.

```
data want;
  set have;
  by ID PREFER;
  if first.id then group=0;
  group+first.prefer;
  if group=1;
run;
```